# Cannot run ajax javascript code

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, ajax

I try to run the below javascript code but it does not work. (it does not return the alert pop up)  I put the url string into a browser, it return the item info.  So, I assume the url is fine.  And the server return the information I want.

URL to brower:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<Listname>')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="myurl/_api/"; xmlns="w3.org/2005/Atom"; xmlns:d="schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"; xmlns:m="schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"; xmlns:georss="georss.org/georss"; xmlns:gml="opengis.net/gml">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:FileName>attached_filename.csv</d:FileNa‌​me>
            <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/DART/Lists/test/Attachments/1/attached_filename.csv</d:S‌​erverRelativeUrl>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry></feed>
```

But why the code stop here?  What is wrong? in the code? in the server?
Any help is appreciated.  Thank you so much!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + name + "')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/",
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) { alert('succ');},
    error: function() {alert('err');}
  });
```

I am including the following before the script:

```
<script type="text\javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">; </script>
```

After I looked into the error info, I found the $ is underfined error.
Any idea why? How can I defined $?  Thanks!
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined it is near the ajax.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27507/discussion-on-question-by-jw120-cannot-run-ajax-javascript-code).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon from your jquery definition tag. It should look something like:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Text between tags that should reference external scripts will mess things up.